# Make Node.js websocket client run indefinitely

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws

I'm using `ws` library to handle Websocket connections client-side.

Here's example from `ws` docs (https://github.com/websockets/ws#usage-examples):

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The problem is that this program exits after receiving just the first message from server.

How do I make it run and listen for messages indefinitely?

Comment: Add your backend Code also.
is there is any error in backend ?

Comment: Add: `client.on('close', () => console.log('closed'));` to see when it's closing, is it immediately after sending the message?. You're probably ending the connection on the backend,